# Intel graphics not supported

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

I have a Lenovo laptop with Intel Iris graphics (i7-1065G7) and discrete NVIDIA GPU on Ubuntu 20.10. I've had high cpu usage and power consumption for a while and I only now realized that it may be because it's using the discrete GPU instead of integrated.

I installed `mate-optimus-applet` to change the GPU settings and this is the output:

```
mate-optimus-applet: launched.
  - nvidia-settings and prime-select detected.
  - prime-supported: Yes
mate-optimus-applet: NVIDIA Optimus supported.
Checking: intel
  - intel loaded: No
  - intel: is not supported
Checking: nvidia
  - nvidia loaded: n/a
  - prime-supported: Yes
  - nvidia-detector: nvidia-driver-455
  - prime-select: nvidia detected.
  - nvidia: is supported
Checking: on-demand
  - on-demand loaded: n/a
  - prime-supported: Yes
  - nvidia-detector: nvidia-driver-455
  - prime-select: on-demand detected.
  - on-demand: is supported
  - nvidia-settings and prime-select detected.
```

Note the entry saying intel drivers were not loaded and not supported.

The Optimus menu also displays only the NVIDIA card, with options to switch between performance and on-demand modes. I want to disable discrete graphics and use only Intel.

I'm not sure what other information I should provide here, so if there's anything missing please do comment and I shall respond immediately.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS/UEFI Settings for any that disable the discrete GPU?

Comment: @ubfan1 that seems to have done it, thanks. The BIOS had options to switch between discrete and UMA graphics - turns out UMA means the intel gpu. Now the question is how do I switch between GPUs without rebooting every time like I do on my other devices